# Showing that mean value theorem does not hold for $c(t)=(\cos t,\sin t, t)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am trying to show that the mean value theorem does not hold for the continuously differentiable function
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad c:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3, \;\;c(t)=(\cos t,\sin t, t)$
This means that there exist $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ for which there is no $\tau\in (a,b)$, such that
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad c(b)-c(a)=(b-a)*c'(\tau)$

As there is $\cos$ and $\sin$ involved I chose $a=0$ and $b= \pi$. Hence:
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad c(b)-c(a)=(-1, 0, \pi)-(1, 0, 0)=(-2, 0, \pi)$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (b-a)*c'(\tau)=\pi * (-\sin\tau, \cos\tau, 1)=(-\pi\sin\tau, \pi\cos\tau, \pi)$
For $\pi\cos\tau$ to be equal to $0$, $\tau$ must be equal to a multiple of $\pi/2$, which means that $\pi\sin\tau = -\pi$, because $\sin \pi/2=1$.
$(a,b)=(0,\pi)\implies c(b)-c(a)=(-2, 0, \pi)\neq (-\pi,0,\pi)=(b-a)*c'(\tau)$
Therefore the mean value theorem does not hold for $c:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3, \;\;c(t)=(\cos t,\sin t, t)$
I'd appreciate if you could point out any mistakes in my working

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is correct but it can be simplified. When you observed that $\tau$ must be a multiple of $\frac {\pi} 2$ remember that you also want $ \tau \in (0,\pi)$. Hence $\tau$ must be exactly $\pi /2$ and then  it becomes clear that $c(b)-c(a)=(b-a)c'(\tau)$ is not satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

You need $t\in(a,b)$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{b-a}(c(b)-c(a))=c'(t)
$$
that is,
$$
\left(\frac{\cos b-\cos a}{b-a},\frac{\sin b-\sin a}{b-a},1\right)=(-\sin t,\cos t,1)
$$
With $a=0$ and $b=\pi$, this becomes
$$
\left(-\frac{2}{\pi},0,1\right)=(-\sin t,\cos t,1)
$$
which clearly fails, because $\cos t=0$ implies $\sin t=1$ in the specified interval.

More generally, the equality implies that
$$
(\cos b-\cos a)^2+(\sin b-\sin a)^2=(b-a)^2
$$
that simplifies to
$$
2-2\cos(b-a)=(b-a)^2
$$
If $k=(b-a)/2$, we get
$$
\sin^2k=k^2
$$
Note that, for $k>0$, $\sin k<k$. Therefore the mean value theorem fails on *every* interval.